# Find document that contains at least one element of an string array

Tags: mongodb

I want to run a query in MongoDB that return distinct documnets of a collection that include at least one of the element of an array of strings. For example if I have a list that include A,B,C, the query should return all distinct documents that include "A" **OR** "B" **OR** "C".  I have written this query:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("A", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));
query.append("B", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)).
append("C", new Basicstrong textDBObject("$exists", true));
```

but it returns all document that have "A" **AND** "B" **AND** "C". How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have explicitly `$or` the documents.

```
BasicDBList orList = new BasicDBList();
orList.add(new BasicDBObject("A", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));
orList.add(new BasicDBObject("B", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));
orList.add(new BasicDBObject("C", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));

BasicDBObject or = new BasicDBObject("$or", orList);
```

Comment: That is a good idea and works properly but the run time is high. Is there another way? @Veeram